# How does Illya overpower Alter Saber's Excalibur with her traced version?

Tags: fate-kaleid-liner-prisma-illya

A [traced Noble Phantasm](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Tracing#Projection_.28Trace_Version.29) should be one rank below that of the original.

How was Illya able to overcome the difference in power?

Clearly she traced [Excalibur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qbMk.png) and not [Caliburn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf8nN.jpg).

[image: Trace-on!]

Comment: She's is still a grail in Kalied

Comment: @Valvatorez: I don't think there is anything in the manga that directly says so, but I am not surprise if that is the case, since Miyu is confirmed to be a grail vessel (?) in Drei, and both Miyu and Ilya has the same ability to Install cards directly.

Comment: @nhahtdh in the wiki it says Ilya was born to be utilized in Heaven's Feel and that Ilya's magical ability was sealed when Kiritsugu and Irisviel decided not to go though with it, since the alternate reality is that the 4th war is actually the first, Ilya's purpose in the ritual may have been the same as Justeaze Lizrich von Einzbern and that was to become the core of the ritual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that Archerko Illya traced Excalibur and overloaded it with prana turning it into a [Broken Phantasm](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Noble_Phantasm). Which raises the weapon's rank by one.

One would assume that the two Excaliburs would cancel each other out, but Saber Alter, unlike the typical Saber only has an Magic Resistance of [Rank B](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Saber_%28Fate/stay_night%29#Magic_Resistance) since her Alignment is Lawful Evil, which might make her more vulnerable to the effects of Excalibur.

Answer (score 0):

She was able to accomplish this through her stored mana. She's like Sakura, and Avenger, a (Psudo)Holy Grail to put it simply